# Is there a geo-referenced directory of hospitals, labs, providers and their network affiliations for the US and Canada?

Tags: geospatial, medical

Is there a geo-referenced directory of hospitals, labs, providers and their provider network affiliations for the US and Canada? I would prefer a dataset that has both street address and lat lon, but street address will do.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think so... in Canada I'm pretty sure this data is provincial... I'm not sure about the US, there may be something more national...

https://catalogue.data.gov.bc.ca/dataset/bc-health-care-facilities-hospital

https://catalogue.data.gov.bc.ca/dataset/bc-community-health-atlas

http://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset?q=hospital&catalog_type=Geo+Data+%7C+G%C3%A9o

Answer (score 0):

I don't think has any information on provider network affiliations, but could be a start: https://healthsites.io/

Comment: Looks pretty new and mainly a splash page. Doesn't look like a data product yet.